# jQuery NOT selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('input[name=myCheck]').change(function() {
   $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

How do I say: removeAttr('checked') for everybody except this?

Comment: I have nothing to add on the given answer. But you should use `id` instead of the `name` attribute to find your input element; it will be much faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function to filter out the element(s) you don't want.  In this case, use `this` (which refers to the changed DOM `<input>` element in the handler), like this:

```
$('input[name=myCheck]').change(function() {
   $('input:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

As a side note, [`.attr('checked', false)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) also works...or since you only want one checked, consider using a set of radio buttons instead, with no JavaScript at all.

Comment: I'm telling you what: I stand in awe of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Everything except for what, checkboxes or inputs named myCheck?

Either way, it's either in-line using:

```
:not(<selector>)
```

or you can use

```
$('<global selector>').not('<exclusion selector>')
```

*Made this an answer instead of a comment*